# Why did Naksu suffer a loss of power upon shifting souls?

Tags: alchemy-of-souls

Most soul shifters that we see on *Alchemy of Souls* are able to use their powers without difficulty upon shifting bodies. However, when Naksu shifts bodies near the beginning of the series, she finds that her powers are inhibited to the point that she is unable to use them unless she is in the presence of a strong external source of power that she can draw upon, such as the lake or the ice stone.

Naksu initially attributes this to her new body being too "weak," magically speaking, to perform spells, much as happened with Jang Gang when he switched bodies with the dying king. However, while this seemed perfectly plausible when it seemed that Naksu simply had taken over the body of Mu-Deok, a random person, we now know that

> she *highly coincidentally*  (or not?) ended up in the body of Bu-Yeon, the daughter of the head of Jinyowon and a powerful mage and priestess with no difficulty casting spells, and who would have trained in such arts from early childhood.

It seems clear that the "weakness" of Naksu's current body cannot be the issue. As such, why did Naksu lose access to her powers upon shifting souls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Teacher Lee, whom we can probably trust, since he is the only person on the show thus far to have reached the level of Hwansu, Naksu's body was containing her powers precisely because Bu-Yeon (whom we know to be somewhat alive) was preventing her from using them. This would make a great deal of sense, since Bu-Yeon presumably is not too pleased with her  body being controlled by someone else. Alternately, she may even have been protecting Naksu—she does not seem very hostile when we see her, and her containing Naksu's powers was precisely what prevented her from running wild. Or for that matter, she may have been protecting herself: if Naksu's body were to petrify, it would be *Bu-Yeon's body* that would petrify.

Admittedly, Lee does refer to Naksu's body as weak again here—so perhaps it was, although that did not seem to be a major problem for Bu-Yeon—but he is clear that the *only* thing that could have contained the powers of such a powerful mage for so long a time would be the powers of a very strong priestess.

Indeed, we saw that when Jin Mu broke this barrier and allowed Naksu the renewed use of her powers, any issues with Bu-Yeon's body not being strong enough to support the use of spells seemed to be very minor, if at all relevant.